# How can I upload Web jobs in virtual machine on Azure server?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I was using Web sites,web jobs on **Azure server** for development purpose 
but now client give me Virtual Machine for hosting the Web sites and Web jobs,
I hosted web sites on IIS server on Virtual machine and its working fine
 but I have no idea how I will host web job in **Virtual Machine** on Azure Server.

Thanks

Comment: Is it an option for you to use a web app rather than a VM ?

Answer (score 4):

According to your requirement, I assumed that you could try to deploy [Kudu engine](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) to your VM for managing the execution of your WebJobs.
You could refer to this [tutorial](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Getting-started) and this [blog](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/06/developing-kudu-locally-and-on-azure.html) for getting started with Kudu.

Here is my test locally, you could refer to it.

[image]

[image]